# How to ensure data is not loaded twice in Redux Saga?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

Let's say, I have a simple `React` application with `Redux` and `Redux-Saga`. I want to load some data, but want to ensure, that the data is NOT loaded twice. The data will be requested multiple times.

My naive implementation is the following:

```
function* loadMyData() {
    const isMyDataLoaded = yield select(isMyDataLoadedSelector);
    if (!isMyDataLoaded) {
        yield call(loadMyData);
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are plenty of ways to achieve this, including the one you mentioned - which is fine imo.

Another way to do this could be to wait for the load action just once:

```
function * loadMyDataSaga() {
   yield call(loadMyData);
}

function * watcher() {
    yield take(ACTIONS.LOAD_DATA);
    yield fork(loadMyDataSaga);
}
```

The `take` effect - unlike `takeEvery` - will wait for LOAD_DATA action only once. Any subsequent dispatches of LOAD_DATA will be ignored.

You could also implement some sort of memoization cache on top of `loadMyData` aside from the redux/redux-saga layers. This would be useful if you ever load your data from other places than from the sagas.

Comment: What if the `loadMyData` call fails the first time?

Comment: @DávidMolnár good point, you could wrap the api call in try..catch and start another watcher in case of an error.